# How to use a table value in a custom SQL - Tableau Prep

Tags: plsql, tableau-api

In Tableau Prep I have an output table that I want to import into an Oracle database.

In that output table, there's a column (file_date) with a date value (ex.: '2021-01-01'). The date value is the same for **all rows**.

**Output table:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6YJz.png)

I need to write a custom SQL query (in Tableau Prep) that checks if my Oracle table already has any rows where the date = '2021-01-01'. If so, all rows need to be deleted before I import the new data.

**Table_1:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmexF.png)

Something like:

```
DELETE FROM table_1 WHERE date_column = '2021-01-01';
```

After checking it will find that the 1st row has the date = '2021-01-01' and **deletes that row.**

**Table_1 after:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cV3u.png)

As the date changes every time new files come up, manually entering the date in the query is not a possibility. **Is there any way to use a value from my table in a custom SQL query?**

I'm aware that Tableau Desktop allows for the creation of parameters, but that's not available in Tableau Prep.

Comment: Welcome to the SO Community, The community will help you with issues. But there are certain expectations. Please take a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to review [ask]. Post table definition (ddl) and sample data, as text - **no images**. For this there are defiantly ways other than changing the query each time.  But how do you know what the date is? Is it the oldest date on your table? The newest? Is it on a parameter table? You get a memo from Bill in accounting? Others? Without that it is impracticable to suggest how to automate this.

Comment: @Belayer in the output (in Tableau Prep) the date is the same for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

If the output is all the same date, then that must also be true of the input data. There is no reason to check for existing data values. Since finding no matching records on delete does not throw an error, checking is not necessary - just delete.

```
delete 
  from table_1 
 where date_column =  
       (select date_column 
          from import_table_1 
          fetch first 1 row only  
       );
```

Comment: This query will be in Tableau Prep (as a custom SQL query), so my question was how can I reference the data/table in Tableau? In Tableau (as far as I know) it's not possible to do a `SELECT whatever_column from import_table` because it won't recognize the table or column like a normal SQL query does.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what Tableau Prep. However, if it import_table is an defined table, a view, a inline view/CTE it should accept it. If it does not it is very very limited in SQL. That is a basic form of query. Have you actually tried it? What were the results?

Comment: Tableau Prep allows for the use of SQL, but in a very limited way hence the reason why I posted this question. Thank you anyway, I'll just have to keep searching different options.

Comment: Did you actually try it? That **is** a very basic query. The only part that is relatively new is *fetch first row only*. If that dose not work try *rownum <= 1* ( a much older version).